# Javascript Regex Catch Word

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to catch word in paragraphy. I do not want to use word boundary because of unicode character (şöüİıçğ) problems. So I use a regex like this. I get an error Invalid group. Is there someone who can help?

```
var paragraphy= "Bu örnek bir metindir <span>bu</span> metin; test amaçlı yazılmıştır.";
var word="metin;";
var regex = new RegExp("([\\s>]|^)("+word+")(?=([\\.\\,\\;\\?\\!](?=[\\s<])|(?<![\\.\\,\\;\\?\\!])[<\\s]|$))", "gi");
console.log(paragraphy.match(regex));
```

I want to this result: ["metin"]

Comment: `(?<!...)` is a negative lookbehind and JS doesn't support it.

Comment: @anubhava Well, what can i do?

Comment: What's expected output for above input?

Comment: @anubhava I want to this result: ["metin"] so only word non punctuation

Comment: Will [`(?:[\s>]|^)(metin)(?=[.,;?!]?(?:[<\s]|$))`](https://regex101.com/r/oD5oM9/1) work for you?

Comment: @anubhava Much better pattern than mine because clear and simply. But result: "metin;"

Comment: No result is `metin` only. `;` after `metin` is just a lookahead.

Comment: @anubhava I try to do this: paragraphy.replace(regex, '<span>metin</span>'); and final result: paragraphy= "Bu örnek bir metindir <span>bu</span> <span>metin</span>; test amaçlı yazılmıştır.";

Comment: Do you not want `;` in replaced string?

Comment: @anubhava Yes I not want ; in replaced string

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the boundary check with `([\\s>]|^)` group before the word, and `(?=[.,;?!\\s<])` lookahead after. Also, since you are using a global flag, and you define capture groups, and you need to access one after matching, you'd better use a `RegExp#exec()` inside a loop.

Also, if you have some punctuation after it (inside the search word) you should get rid of it first. If it only appears *at the end of the word*, pre-process it with `word = word.replace(/[,.;?!<]+$/, '')`.

```js
var paragraphy = "Bu örnek bir metindir <span>bu</span> metin; test amaçlı yazılmıştır.";
var word="metin;";
var regex = new RegExp("([\\s>]|^)("+word.replace(/[,.;?!<]+$/, '')+")(?=[.,;?!\\s<])", "gi");
res = paragraphy.replace(regex, '$1<span>metin</span>');
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + res + "</pre>";
```

```css
span {
  color: #FF0000;
  }
```

Comment: must be word="metin;" and result only word this "metin" so not punctuation

Comment: When you want to search for `metin;` there is no chance to return just `metin`. Regexps do not work that way - **you must pre-process the pattern *before* searching**.

Comment: I try to do this: paragraphy.replace(regex, '<span>metin</span>'); and final result: paragraphy= "Bu örnek bir metindir <span>bu</span> <span>metin</span>; test amaçlı yazılmıştır.";

Answer (score 1):

Based on discussion above (below your question) you can use this `replace`:

```js
    var word = "metin";

    var re = new RegExp("(^|[\\s>])(" + word + ")[.,;?!]?(?=[\\s<]|$)", "gi");

    var str = 'Bu örnek bir metindir <span>bu</span> metin; test amaçlı yazılmıştır';
     
    var result = str.replace(re, '$1<span>$2</span>');

    alert(result);
```

```
//=> Bu örnek bir metindir <span>bu</span> <span>metin</span> test amaçlı yazılmıştır
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oD5oM9/2)

Comment: Thank you for helps me I guess. I need to reconsider all script @anubhava